# Create a Video Gallery?

Tags: sharepoint-online, video

I'm trying to create a Video Gallery for a post to show the work-in-progress of a project.
I want to display the videos in a similar way to how the Image Gallery is laid out. Confined into one window space. So it would look something like this - [image: image gallery]

I have scoured the web for answers but cannot find anything on the Sharepoint forums. I found some info about embedding with code but this is out of my comfort zone!
If anyone has any suggestions or solutions that would be amazing!
Many thanks
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online, you can create an Asset library to store videos and add web part to display that library in a modern page. However we do not have a video visualization experience in it. It is still like a library. If you want to have a better experience, it is recommended to use the stream web part to display the videos stored in Stream.

**Stream:**
[image]

**Asset Library:**
[image]

How to use stream in SharePoint Online:https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/stream/embed-video-sharepoint